# Passing an argument to a scheduled class method

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have created a schedulable class

```
global class ScheduledClassTesting Implements Schedulable{

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
         testScheduleClass();
         System.abortJob( sc.getTriggerId() );
      }

    public void testScheduleClassMethod(string argPass){

    }

}
```

However it doesnot allow me to save as it give the following error(which makes sense).

```
Save error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: testScheduleClass()
```

Is it possible to create a method similar to `testScheduleClassMethod()` which accept's an argument(type string) at the time it is being scheduled?

Comment: we already have this question in site and i remember we have solution for same.please search here

Comment: Hey Mohith, if possible can you direct me to that link. Thanks!!!

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14634/passing-parameter-into-schedulable-class               please find the link

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
{
     string test='';
     testScheduleClassMethod(test);
     System.abortJob( sc.getTriggerId() );
  }

public void testScheduleClassMethod(string argPass){

}
```

Comment: Yes, this allows me to save the code without any errors. But is there a way to pass the argument while I am scheduling it? Is so will this statement `string test='';` override the value being passed?

Comment: Where is the argument originating from?

Comment: I am scheduling the function using `System.schedule('TestSchedule' + sysTime, chronExpression, new ScheduledClassTesting ())`. I want to pass it at the time of schedule along with `...new ScheduledClassTesting ())`.

Comment: so basically the argument will be passed at the time the class is scheduled.

Comment: Ah I see. What if you has a static variable in another class that you set when scheduling and referenced that from inside the schedule class?

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me error saying you cannot access static variable from object instance.

Comment: Hm its hard to know what's going on without seeing the code, but you don't need to instantiate the class. Take a look at this example of accessing a static variable in another class: http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/cookbook/Content/apex_controlling_recursive_triggers.htm Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

What about passing parameters through constructor and storing them in global instance variables?

```
global class Dummy_Schedulable_Class implements Schedulable{ 

    global List<String> names;
    global List<String> cronExpressions;

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, names );
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, cronExpressions );
        testScheduleClassMethod(names[0]);
    }

    public void testScheduleClassMethod(string argPass){

    }

    public Dummy_Schedulable_Class ( List<String> aNames, List<String> aCronExps) {
        if ( names == null ) {
            names = aNames;
        } else {
            names.addAll(aNames);
        }
        if ( cronExpressions == null ) {
            cronExpressions = aCronExps;
        } else {
            cronExpressions.addAll(aCronExps);
        }
    }

}
```